# Get index of element in array and search for it in another array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I want to get the index of an element which I'm looking for using `in_array("Tuesday", $day)` and get the element from another array on the same position as this one. I have 2 arrays: `$day` and `$action`. I need some help with this, I'm stuck.

Comment: It's not really clear what you ask, but [array_search](http://us3.php.net/array_search) might be a good start.

Comment: Ok, so I'm using the `in_array` like this: 
`if(in_array("Tuesday, $day)){}`. If it is in array, I want to take it's position in the array and print the element on the same position from the other array.

Comment: the in_array won't return you any index, it's just a boolean, array_search does the same job and returns the key, ex: 
`$key = array_search("Tuesday, $day);
if $key > 0 
   // do stuff (and you can of course do $action[$key]`

Comment: Can you please post this as an answer, so I can accept it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the in_array won't return you any index, it's just a boolean, array_search does the same job and returns the key, ex:

```
$key = array_search("Tuesday", $day); 
if($key !== false)
   // do stuff (and you can of course do $action[$key]
```

Comment: `if ($key > 0)` is wrong. Just read the documentation: `if ($key !== false)` is correct.